# Laravel 9 Eloquent - How to get entities that have certain properties in a ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hello to everybody.

Please help with a query via Eloquent.

I have Building and Pictogram models. Among them is the manyToMany relationship with the connection table. Everything works normally. But I can't figure out how to get Buildings that definitely have Pictograms attached to them. I know how to make a query that returns Buildings that have at least one of the Pictograms I specified.

Example:

```
$buildings->whereHas("pictograms", function (Builder $query) use ($selected_pictograms){
   $query->whereIn("slug", $selected_pictograms);
});
```

but I don't know how to get the Buildings that have all of the Pictograms I specified.

Thank you for your help

I'm trying combinations of different procedures using `whereIn()` or `whereRelation()` or `has()` and it still fails

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `whereHas` takes 2 more arguments: `whereHas($relation, Closure $callback = null, $operator = '>=', $count = 1)`  ... so you could specify that you only want buildings having a specific count of pictograms (from the list specified)

Comment: also I think you forgot the `->get()` ?